# iPhone OS current usage statistics (esp. 2.x vs 3.x)

Tags: iphone, macos, usage-statistics

I am trying to find out how many of the active iPhone and iPod touch users have at least 3.0 OS installed.

I need to know if the percentage running 2.x is still considerable or not really.

I tried looking into AdMob stats, and other OS usage stats sites, 
but I can't get to see iPhone 2.x vs iPhone 3.x

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021929/what-percentage-of-iphone-users-have-the-different-versions-of-iphone-os-firmware and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/659911/iphone-installed-base-upgrade-rate

Comment: As you can see, these questions aren't that useful here, because they are only true for a specific point in time.

Comment: Well, Brad I was hoping somebody has a link where certain company publishes current stats every month like the ones for Computer OS or Browser usage, which I definitely didn't find myself nor here or in google

Comment: Zlib: Sorry if I came across as harsh, I just meant to say that it's difficult to have a canonical answer to a question like this, because install stats are a moving target.  If there was one central site that maintained up-to-date information on this, that could be an answer, but as you can see the best we can do is cobble together anecdotal evidence.

Comment: Brad is right, apparently there's no correct and informative resource which keeps up-to-date usage data ... how to I close this question then ?

Answer (score 3):

As of January 2010, shortly before the release of 3.1.3:

At around 30,000 downloads (mostly in Austria, some in Germany) for one of our free apps, there are **fewer than 5% of devices still on 2.2.1 or older** (as reported by `UIDevice`).

Less than a quarter was not on the latest OS Release (3.1.2 at the time).

Answer (score 1):

It's good to know the ratio 2.x VS 3.x but you may also ask yourself "Let's consider someone who is still using 2.x : is this person really a potential user of your app or an appstore user ?" . In my opinion : no.

So targeting below 3.0 does not make any sense IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Quick note, referring to iPhone OS 2.1.1 in user agent is used by most bots which claim to be iPhone.

Comment: By bots you mean web spiders or something else? Do you have a link where I could read more ?

Comment: Web spiders mostly and then some applications which crawl through the web site to create some fancy-looking but practically pointless UI fluff (think of the 3D navigation thingies available for Google Image Search). No links available, but there's already close to a hundred lawyers from a dozen or so service providers who know of these and are proactively fighting against them. Additionally iPhone OS 2.1.1 is also one of the most popular jailbreaked OS' out there. Yeah, iPhone's popularity has somehow also allowed people to show their ugly side too...

Answer (score 0):

After a look around, I have found this (which hopefully, will be of some use to you):
http://tapbots.com/blog/news/iphone-os-30-adoption-rate

Hope this helps!

(Data from: June 23rd, 2009)

Comment: hi, thanks, I've found this one too, but I think after the last Christmas (which was very strong for the iPod touch) the picture has definitely changed a lot. that's why I did put "current" in the title of my question

Comment: I think you will be lucky to find 2010 usage statistics this early in the year. If you do find any, please post up here though! Best of luck.

Comment: I know it'll be hard, I tought AdMob definitely has enough data to put together some stats, but ... no luck

Answer (score 0):

Check out flurry.com.  They have a free SDK that take about two lines of code to start tracking all kinds of cool details like OS version, type of device, device version, location, what wireless carrier was used, WI-FI use, etc.

Answer (score 0):

http://insights.chitika.com/2011/ios-update-ipads-iphones-running-high-rate-of-ios-4/

More recent data. (Bottom line: 4.0+ is effectively ubiquitous on iPhones--91% adoption.)

Answer (score 0):

I usually use Chitika

http://insights.chitika.com/2011/just-in-time-for-ios-5-ios-3-almost-dead/